# how to compare date which is given by user to date in javascript..?

Tags: javascript

In my web-site I am getting  a date from user which in format like "dd-mm-yyyy",now I want to get the date which is 7-day before of that user's date.
I am able to get the current date in format "dd-mm-yyyy" but how would  I know the date which is one week before user's date in javascript?

Comment: Suppose I am getting two dates like start date as 29/11/2012 and last date as 29/12/2012.Now how to compare these two dates,so I can notify  user before 7-days of last date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this--**

```
 var MyDate = new Date('11/30/2012');  //date format in mm/dd/yyyy
 MyDate.setDate(MyDate.getDate() -7)
 var newDate = MyDate.getMonth()+1 + '/' + MyDate.getDate() + '/' +    MyDate.getFullYear()
 alert(newDate);
```

Note- subtracting seven days to a date shifts the month or year and the changes are handled automatically by the Date object.

Comment: Not like that they aren't. `getDate` returns an integer, try `myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() - 7)`.

Comment: in above code in what format should I pass the value of 'your date value',its possible to send date value like 'dd-mm-yyyy'?

Comment: I have made few changes in the code. If the previous version was ok ill rollback it, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a `Date` object, use `yourDate.setDate(yourDate.getDate() - 7 );`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use datejs, it's the best date related js library I have seen. Chcek the documentation here.
http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation

Search for add method

Comment: Not sure there's a need for a library when one line of code will likely do the job anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Set Dates

We can easily manipulate the date by using the methods available for the Date object.

In the example below we set a Date object to a specific date (14th January 2010):

```
var myDate=new Date();

myDate.setFullYear(2010,0,14);
```

And in the following example we set a Date object to be 7 days in past:

```
var myDate=new Date(); //or users date
```

// myDate will be users current date

```
myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate()-7);
```

//now substract 7 days to get the date u want.

Follow the following link

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp

Or follow this

http://www.techrepublic.com/article/manipulate-time-and-date-values-with-javascripts-date-object/6076869

Comment: Please don't reference W3Schools. Reference sections of [ECMA-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/) with examples from relevant parts of [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Gecko_DOM_Reference) and [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/windows/apps/br212882.aspx) as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a date string in the format dd-mm-yyyy to a date object using:

```
function toDate(d) {
    d = d.split('-');
    return new Date(d[2], --d[1], d[0]);
}
```

Then use Osiris' answer to add or subtract 7 days.